# zend $acl->has() recource bt $acl->isAllowed returning false

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

I am facing a strange problem with zend_acl, I have successfully added role and resources , but the isAllowed() function is always redirecting to the error controller.

```
$usersNs->role = 'admin';

$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role($usersNs->role));
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource("dashboard::stats"));

$privilageName = $request->getControllerName()."::".$request->getActionName();

if($acl->has($privilageName)){
    echo "has privelage";    //echo every time whenever i go to dashboard,stats
}

if(!$acl->isAllowed($usersNs->role,$privilageName )) {
    $request->setControllerName('error');
    $request->setActionName('error');
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted does not specify which roles should be able to access which resources. Are you doing that elsewhere? If not, that's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: thanks man, that was my mistake i forgot to assign the resources to the roles, I guess I was in some hurry. I could't get to sleep, last night. :)